# Opencv highgui cannot draw rectangle while zoomed in

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an image in opencv using mouse call back.I can zoom in the image by my mouse wheels.After i zoom in the image all i can do is pan around the image and i cannot draw the rectangle.

[the image after I zoom in (only panning is possible here and cannot draw the rectangle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWVSb.png)

I created the window by

```
 namedWindow("lena", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
```

the mouse call back by the function

```
cvSetMouseCallback("lena",mouse_call_pattern);
```

Is there any way to draw the rectangle after i zoom in the image??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you zoom in/out images, but the basic idea is deciding the scale changed every time on mouse wheel.

After you get the current scale (v.s. origin image), the region of image you want to show on screen will be successfully calculated, and you can get the position and length of rectangle on scaled image.

So you will be able to draw this rectangle on scaled image.

In my [github](https://github.com/DennisLiu1993/Zoom-In-Out-with-OpenCV/blob/main/README.md)，check MouseCallBack () and RefreshImage (), two member function of class COpenCVWindowExt.

This project can zoom in/out and pan image only using opencv window.

Key part of the code is as followed:

```
void MouseCall (int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* pUserData)
{
    COpenCVWindowExt* pParent = (COpenCVWindowExt*)pUserData;
    if (event == EVENT_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        if (getMouseWheelDelta (flag) > 0 && pParent->m_iScaleTimes != pParent->m_iMaxScaleTimes)
            pParent->m_iScaleTimes++;
        else if (getMouseWheelDelta (flag) < 0 && pParent->m_iScaleTimes != pParent->m_iMinScaleTimes)
            pParent->m_iScaleTimes--;

        if (pParent->m_iScaleTimes == 0)
            pParent->m_dCompensationX = pParent->m_dCompensationY = 0;

        //Pixel value = mouse offset (v.s. window's left top position)
        //But using x, y is not correct in Wheel Event. So, use pre recorded value
        x = pParent->m_iMouseX;
        y = pParent->m_iMouseY;
        double dPixelX = (pParent->m_iHorzScrollBarPos + x + pParent->m_dCompensationX) / pParent->m_dNewScale;
        double dPixelY = (pParent->m_iVertScrollBarPos + y + pParent->m_dCompensationY) / pParent->m_dNewScale;

        pParent->m_dNewScale = pParent->m_dInitialScale * pow (pParent->m_dScaleRatio, pParent->m_iScaleTimes);

        if (pParent->m_iScaleTimes != 0)
        {
            int iWidth = pParent->m_matSrc.cols;
            int iHeight = pParent->m_matSrc.rows;

            pParent->m_iHorzScrollBarRange_Max = int (pParent->m_dNewScale * iWidth - pParent->m_dInitialScale * iWidth) - 1;
            pParent->m_iVertScrollBarRange_Max = int (pParent->m_dNewScale * iHeight - pParent->m_dInitialScale * iHeight) - 1;
            int iBarPosX = pParent->m_iHorzScrollBarPos = int (dPixelX * pParent->m_dNewScale - x + 0.5);
            int iBarPosY = pParent->m_iVertScrollBarPos = int (dPixelY * pParent->m_dNewScale - y + 0.5);
            pParent->m_dCompensationX = -iBarPosX + (dPixelX * pParent->m_dNewScale - x);
            pParent->m_dCompensationY = -iBarPosY + (dPixelY * pParent->m_dNewScale - y);
        }
        else
        {
            pParent->m_iHorzScrollBarPos = 0;
            pParent->m_iVertScrollBarPos = 0;
        }
        pParent->RefreshImage ();
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        pParent->m_iMouseX = x;
        pParent->m_iMouseY = y;

    }
}
```

Effect:
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image: ![enter image description here]